# vhost_alias_module domain.com doesn't go to www.domain.com

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using the configuration below to use vhost_alias_module to more easily manage my hosted setup.  I want sites to be structured like the following /sites/domain.com/w/w/w/ which with the configuration below works fine.  However, if I attempt to access domain.com instead of www.domain.com this falls apart.  How do I fix this?

**Update**: I want request for domain.com to automatically be directed to www.domain.com.  It would be fine if this required a 403 redirect (I think that would be preferred from a SEO perspective) .

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com

        DocumentRoot /sites/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /sites/>;
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /sites/%2+/%1.1/%1.2/%1.3+

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How do you want it to behave?  `/sites/domain.com/`?  `/sites/domain.com/d/o/m`?  Or requests without a subdomain imply `www`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden good point I did forget to write that.  :-)  Imply www if it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the requirement to imply `www` comes close to pushing you out of being able to use mod_vhost_alias, and into mod_rewrite territory.. but there's a couple options that I can think of:

1. Just redirect to `www`.

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   # Match anything with a two-part name
   # (will not work for 3-part base domains that would need to redirect to www, be careful)
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
   # Redirect
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
   ```
2. Let those requests work without a redirect, and use symlink trickery to stick them to the www location.

   With your `VirtualDocumentRoot`, requests to `domain.com` go to `/sites/com/d/o/m` - let's change that:

   ```
   VirtualDocumentRoot /sites/%-2+/%-3.1/%-3.2/%-3.3+
   ```

   This will make a request for `domain.com` go to `/sites/domain.com/_/_/_` - make this location a symlink to `/sites/domain.com/w/w/w`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 2 seems like a lot of work if I have more than a few domains but would be a quick fix.  Where would I put the mod_rewrite section in #1?  Would that go just before my VirtualDocumentRoot directive?

Comment: @ScottWarren Anywhere in that `<VirtualHost>` block.  And keep in mind that it's pretty rudimentary, it's just looking for two-part names and tacking a `www` on the front; if you have `someapplication.clientdomain.com` that needs to direct to `www.someapplication.clientdomain.com`, it won't work.

Comment: That will work just fine for what I'm planning.